# Como puedo arrancar mi ensamblado en c#

Tags: c#

Hola anteriormente pregunté sobre un error que me devolvía al cargar mi ensamblado. Pero ahora mi pregunta es una vez cargado como lo arranco?
El código de la funcion es.

```
internal static Assembly AssemblyHome(byte[] data)
        {
```

Lo que hago es:

```
var a = AssemblyHome(data);
a.EntryPoint.Invoke(null,null);
```

Mi programa tiene entrypoint y todo, pero una vez que lo escribo luego como puedo invocarlo?

Answer (score 4):

Asumiendo que el `EntryPoint` corresponde a un método `Main` estándar (no sé si es posible que no lo sea), entonces debes pasarle al `Invoke` el parámetro que corresponde al parámetro `args` del `Main`:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // ...
}
```

De modo que dependiendo de qué valor le quieres pasar para el `args`, puedes escoger de entre todas las siguientes variaciones:

```
a.EntryPoint.Invoke(null,new object[] {null}); // args == null
a.EntryPoint.Invoke(null,new object[] {new string[0]}); // args == {}
a.EntryPoint.Invoke(null,new object[] {new string[] {"p1"}}); // args == {"p1"}
a.EntryPoint.Invoke(null,new object[] {new string[] {"p1", "p2"}}); // args == {"p1", "p2"}
// etc.
```

Comment: si pongo new object me devuelve `Array creation must have array size or array initializer (CS1586) -`  si le pongo null a mi objeto `Cannot convert null to 'int' because it is a non-nullable value type (CS0037) - ` lo que estoy haciendo es escribir un byte array digamos ej  `byte[] Array1 = new byte[5]; ` luego como puedo llamarlo ? en mi caso me devuelve los errores citados cuando intento hacerlo. el codigo que intente: `a.EntryPoint.Invoke(null,new object[null]); ` si pongo null me devuelve ese error alo mejor tengo que poner el tamaño del byte?

Comment: Fijate bien, no estás copiando mi código correctamente. Yo en ningún lugar he puesto `new object[null]`, eso es inválido.